# Getlistservice.asmx ignoring caml query

Tags: development, list, web-services

I am using Sharepoint 2013 Online.

I have the following code using the /_vti_bin/lists.asmx web service

```
  XmlDocument camlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNode camlNode = camlDocument.CreateElement("Query");

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.Append("<Where>");
            sb.AppendFormat("<Eq>");
            sb.AppendFormat("<FieldRef Name='Individual' />");
            sb.AppendFormat("<Value Type='Lookup'>John Doe</Value>");
            sb.AppendFormat("</Eq>");
            sb.Append("</Where>");

            camlNode.InnerXml = sb.ToString();
            int rowlimit = 2000;


            XmlNode items = myService.GetListItems("Documents", null, camlNode, null, rowlimit.ToString(), null, null);
```

and when I run it I am getting the following error message:

```
The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.0x80070024
```

The list Documents has 50,000 records. However there is only 90 that have a record that has the individuals name John Doe.

It should be able to return the 90 records? Or can I not query any list that has more than 5000 records?

Answer (score 1):

You need to either increase the List View Threshold or disable resource throttling on the list.

> 1. Navigate to Central Administration.
> 2. Go to Application Management > Manage Web Application and click on your web application to select it.
> 3. In the Ribbon, click on General Settings drop-down and choose “Resource Throttling”.
> 4. In the “List View Threshold”, increase the value (by a factor of 2, for example) and click OK.
> 5. Try to replicate the error.  If the error persists, increase the value again until the error goes away.

Or use PowerShell to disable resource throttling.

```
SPList.EnableThrottling = $false
```

References:
http://sharepointnomad.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/solving-the-attempted-operation-is-prohibited-because-it-exceeds-the-list-view-threshold-error/
http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2012/02/attempted-operation-is-prohibited.html

Comment: I am using Sharepoint Online (Office 365) It can not be changed on this version :(

Comment: Then you may need to Split the items into multiple lists so that no list exceeds 5,000 items. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2759051